# Sumar una fecha en JavaScript dentro de un for

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que sucede es que tengo un código y **lo quiero implementar dentro de un for** o algo en JavaScript de forma que **por ejemplo tengo la fecha 15/09/2018, le sumo de a 15 días para que sea algo como 30/09/2018, 15/10/2018, 30/10/2018 y así...**

```
FechaPrimerPagoInput = $('#input-date').val();
fechaPrimerPago = new Date(FechaPrimerPagoInput);
periocidad = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15;
suma = fechaPrimerPago.getTime() + periocidad;
pagoFecha = new Date(suma);
```

Por favor de su ayuda, es algo sencillo pero no lo se usar con el Date, en la variable periocidad esta al final el 15, que seria cada cuanto contar, pero puede cambiar de 15 a 30.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una posible solución a tu pregunta.

```js
// Out
var resultado = null;

// Objeto Date
resultado = new Date();
// Suma
resultado = resultado.setDate( resultado.getDate() + 15 );      // 15, 30 ...
// Out Resultado 1
console.log(resultado);
// Out Resultado 2
console.log(new Date(resultado));

// Operar con fechas y string
var dateString = "01/01/2018";
var dateParts = dateString.split("/");
var date = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0],1);
// Suma
resultado = new Date(date);
resultado = resultado.setDate( date.getDate() + 15 );           // 15, 30 ...
// Out Resultado 1
console.log(resultado);
// Out Resultado 2
console.log(new Date(resultado));
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirve para mejorar la función que ya tengo, pero realmente lo que necesito es la parte del for

Answer (score 0):

Sacado de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) respuesta:

```js
Date.prototype.agregarDias = function(dias) {
    var fecha = new Date(this.valueOf());
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
    return fecha;
}

var hoy = new Date();

console.log(hoy.agregarDias(15));


console.log(hoy.agregarDias(30));
```

Adentro de un for:

```js
Date.prototype.agregarDias = function(dias) {
    var fecha = new Date(this.valueOf());
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
    return fecha;
}

var hoy = new Date();


for(let i = 15; i<=365; i = i+15){

console.log(hoy.agregarDias(i))

}
```

Eso nos da las fechas cada 15,30,45 días por 365 días. También se podría partir de la fecha anterior, pero es casi lo mismo.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta para mas claridad, lo que realmente necesito es saber como implementarlo dentro de un for

Comment: @JhojanGuerrero actualicé la respuesta, lo hice cada 15 dias, pero esa función podría ser mas compleja si queremos, porque podemos ir cambiando el i adentro del for.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto a ver si es lo que necesitas:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#input-date', function() {
  fecha = $(this).val().match(/(\d+)/g);
  ciclos = 3;
  cantidadFechas = 15;
  fechaPrimerPago = new Date(fecha[0], fecha[1]-1, fecha[2]);
  for (i = 0; i < ciclos; i++) { 
    fechaPrimerPago.setDate(fechaPrimerPago.getDate() + cantidadFechas);
    alert(fechaPrimerPago);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input-date" type="date">
```